# React hooks value is not accessible in event listener function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, react-hooks

I decided to use React hooks for my component using windom width and resize event listener. The problem is that I can't access current value that I need. I get nested value that was set while adding event listener.

Passing function to value setter function is not a solution for me because it's forcing render and breaking my other functionalities.

I am attaching minimalistic example to present core problem:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);

  const resize = () => {
    console.log("width:", width); // it's always 0 even after many updates
    setWidth(window.innerWidth);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    resize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", resize);
  }, []);

  return <div>{width}</div>;
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[LIVE DEMO IS HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-krswmq)

Please for help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Every render you get a new copy of `resize` function. Each copy captures the current value of `width`. Your listener has a copy which was created on the first render with `width = 0`.

To fix this issue you have several options:

1. Update listeners when `width` changes

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     resize();
     window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
     return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", resize);
   }, [width]);
   ```
2. Use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to get the current width inside listener

   ```
   const resize = () => {
     setWidth(oldWidth => {
       console.log("width:", oldWidth);
       return window.innerWidth
     });
   };
   ```
3. Store the width in a [mutable reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

   ```
   const widthRef = useRef(width);

   const resize = () => {
     console.log("width:", widthRef.current);
     widthRef.current = window.innerWidth;
     setWidth(window.innerWidth);
   };
   ```

Comment: Yes it would. The second `useEffect` won't help with the issue. You either need to remove-add listeners when `width` changes or get the current value of the `width` some other way. Hence 3 possible solutions. The first is just the easiest one.

Comment: Your code has bad optimization and doesn't really help with the original issue. It just hides the problem. First `useEffect` sets an event listener which resets `width` to the initial value. This triggers rerender and the second `useEffect`. The second `useEffect`  sets the `width` to a correct value. So each resize event triggers two rerenders instead of one and one of the `resize` calls uses the wrong value.

Comment: I love the 3rd way. Thank you.